# Unable to create sub menu more than two levels in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, woocommerce

I did go through this: https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-create-custom-menu-structures-in-wordpress

I did as per the article above to create sub menu of 3rd level. However, In front end the third level of product category for Woocommerce (green apple) not showing up in the dropdown list.

I also read one of stackoverflow answer which says its not possible to create third-level sub menu. I do believe there's a workaround for this. Please advise me.

Thank you.
[image]

Tried as per @Rafin's answer,

If third level placed after all second level, then it shows up but this is not where the sub menus for second level menu (apple) supposed to be.

**in the backend, placed after all second level menus**

[image]

Shows up this way in front end,

[image]

But I need it to be arranged this way:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following Walker Class that extends **Wordpress Nav Menu**

```
<?php    
class ods_bootstrap_navwalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    /**
     * @see Walker::start_lvl()
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param int $depth Depth of page. Used for padding.
     */
    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
        $output .= "\n$indent<div class=\"drop\"><ul role=\"menu\" class=\" dropdown-menu\">\n";
    }

    /**
     * @see Walker::start_el()
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param object $item Menu item data object.
     * @param int $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param int $current_page Menu item ID.
     * @param object $args
     */
    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        /**
         * Dividers, Headers or Disabled
         * =============================
         * Determine whether the item is a Divider, Header, Disabled or regular
         * menu item. To prevent errors we use the strcasecmp() function to so a
         * comparison that is not case sensitive. The strcasecmp() function returns
         * a 0 if the strings are equal.
         */
        if ( strcasecmp( $item->attr_title, 'divider' ) == 0 && $depth === 1 ) {
            $output .= $indent . '<li role="presentation" class="divider">';
        } else if ( strcasecmp( $item->title, 'divider') == 0 && $depth === 1 ) {
            $output .= $indent . '<li role="presentation" class="divider">';
        } else if ( strcasecmp( $item->attr_title, 'dropdown-header') == 0 && $depth === 1 ) {
            $output .= $indent . '<li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">' . esc_attr( $item->title );
        } else if ( strcasecmp($item->attr_title, 'disabled' ) == 0 ) {
            $output .= $indent . '<li role="presentation" class="disabled"><a href="#">' . esc_attr( $item->title ) . '</a>';
        } else {

            $class_names = $value = '';

            $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
            $classes[] = 'scroll menu-item-' . $item->ID;

            $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );

            if ( $args->has_children )
                $class_names .= ' dropdown';

            if ( in_array( 'current-menu-item', $classes ) )
                $class_names .= ' active';

            $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

            $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
            $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

            $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

            $atts = array();
            $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->title )   ? $item->title  : '';
            $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )  ? $item->target : '';
            $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )     ? $item->xfn    : '';
            $atts['class']    = "back-top";

            // If item has_children add atts to a.
            if ( $args->has_children && $depth === 0 ) {
                $atts['href']           = '#';
                $atts['data-toggle']    = 'dropdown';
                $atts['class']          = 'dropdown-toggle';
                $atts['aria-haspopup']  = 'true';
            } else {
                $atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';
            }

            $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args );

            $attributes = '';
            foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
                if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                    $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                    $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
                }
            }

            $item_output = $args->before;

            /*
             * Glyphicons
             * ===========
             * Since the the menu item is NOT a Divider or Header we check the see
             * if there is a value in the attr_title property. If the attr_title
             * property is NOT null we apply it as the class name for the glyphicon.
             */
            if ( ! empty( $item->attr_title ) )
                $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'><span class="glyphicon ' . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) . '"></span>&nbsp;';
            else
                $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';

            $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
            $item_output .= ( $args->has_children && 0 === $depth ) ? ' <span class="icon-play"></span></a>' : '</a>';
            $item_output .= $args->after;

            $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Traverse elements to create list from elements.
     *
     * Display one element if the element doesn't have any children otherwise,
     * display the element and its children. Will only traverse up to the max
     * depth and no ignore elements under that depth.
     *
     * This method shouldn't be called directly, use the walk() method instead.
     *
     * @see Walker::start_el()
     * @since 2.5.0
     *
     * @param object $element Data object
     * @param array $children_elements List of elements to continue traversing.
     * @param int $max_depth Max depth to traverse.
     * @param int $depth Depth of current element.
     * @param array $args
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @return null Null on failure with no changes to parameters.
     */
    public function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, &$output ) {
        if ( ! $element )
            return;

        $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];

        // Display this element.
        if ( is_object( $args[0] ) )
           $args[0]->has_children = ! empty( $children_elements[ $element->$id_field ] );

        parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
    }

    /**
     * Menu Fallback
     * =============
     * If this function is assigned to the ods_nav_menu's fallback_cb variable
     * and a manu has not been assigned to the theme location in the WordPress
     * menu manager the function with display nothing to a non-logged in user,
     * and will add a link to the WordPress menu manager if logged in as an admin.
     *
     * @param array $args passed from the ods_nav_menu function.
     *
     */
    public static function fallback( $args ) {
        if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {

            extract( $args );

            $fb_output = null;

            if ( $container ) {
                $fb_output = '<' . $container;

                if ( $container_id )
                    $fb_output .= ' id="' . $container_id . '"';

                if ( $container_class )
                    $fb_output .= ' class="' . $container_class . '"';

                $fb_output .= '>';
            }

            $fb_output .= '<ul';

            if ( $menu_id )
                $fb_output .= ' id="' . $menu_id . '"';

            if ( $menu_class )
                $fb_output .= ' class="' . $menu_class . '"';

            $fb_output .= '>';
            $fb_output .= '<li><a href="' . admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' ) . '">Add a menu</a></li>';
            $fb_output .= '</ul>';

            if ( $container )
                $fb_output .= '</' . $container . '>';

            echo $fb_output;
        }
    }
}
```

And you can display menu with

```
<?php
                    wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'menu'              => your_menu_name,
                    'theme_location'    => your_menu_location,
                    'depth'             => 3,
                    'container'         => '',
                    'container_class'   => '',
                    'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                    'menu_class'        => 'navigation',
                    'fallback_cb'       => 'ods_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                    'walker'            => new ods_bootstrap_navwalker())
                    );
                ?>
```

Take a reference to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/

Comment: That is actually a working code and implemented by myself. Can you inspect your navigation menu to check if it is actually missing  your 3rd menu item or not. Might be you have to write proper css for 3rd level of menu item as well to make it visible in web browser. In my case that's what i did once i place the above code.

Comment: I found that, third level menu placed after all the second level menu, showing up. But I need third level for each or some of the second level. For this case its not showing

Comment: Can you show me your working link so that i could inspect it properly and suggest you more precise solution.

Comment: Sorry its still in my localhost, but I edited my post with explanation of that, see if you could understand.

Comment: I think the problem is with the css, I added display:inline for the sub menu and it seems like the third level is there but not showing up correctly. I'll work  on the fix..thanks Rafin for the walker function.

Comment: No problem mate. Happy that you figured out. Good Luck. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The easy code is here you can customize your HTML whatever you want

```
 $parent = array();
      $menu_name = 'menu-1'; //change menu name 
      if (($locations = get_nav_menu_locations()) && isset($locations[$menu_name]))
      {
        $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object($locations[$menu_name]);
        $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
       
        $parent_id = 0;

        foreach((array)$menu_items as $key => $menu_item)
        {
         
          if($menu_item->menu_item_parent == 0)
          {
            $parent_id = $menu_item->db_id;
            $title = $menu_item->title;
            $url = $menu_item->url;
            array_push($parent, array("title" => $title, "url" => $url, "child" => array()));
          }
          else if($menu_item->menu_item_parent == $parent_id)
          {
            $childId = $menu_item->ID;
            $title = $menu_item->title;
            $url = $menu_item->url;
            array_push($parent[count($parent) - 1]["child"], array("ID"=>$childId,"title" => $title, "url" => $url));
          }
        
        
        
        }
      }
    
    foreach($parent as $key=>$childval){
        $parent[$key]['child']['subchild'];
        if (!empty($childval['child'])) {
            for($i=0;$i<count($childval['child']);$i++){
    
       foreach($menu_items as $childitems){
           if($childitems->menu_item_parent==$childval['child'][$i]['ID']){
               $values = array("ID"=>$childitems->ID,"title" => $childitems->title, "url" => $childitems->url);
            $parent[$key]['child'][$i]['childvalue'][] = $values;
           }
       }
            }
        }
        
    }
echo "<pre>";
print_r($parent);
```

?

this will print your array then modify according to you.
thank me later..
the demo HTML is here

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <?php
            
              foreach ($parent as $key => $value)
              {
                if(empty($value["child"]))
                {
                  echo "<li><a href='" . $value["url"] . "'>" . $value["title"] . "</a></li>";
                }
                else
                {
                  echo '<li class="dropdown"><a href="' . $value["url"] . '" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">' . $value["title"] . ' <b class="caret"></b></a><ul class="dropdown-menu">';
                  foreach ($value["child"] as $key => $value)
                  {
                    echo '<li><a href="' . $value["url"] . '">' . $value["title"] . '</a></li>';
                    echo "<ul>";
                    foreach ($value['childvalue'] as $childval ){
                    echo '<li><a href="' . $childval["url"] . '">' . $childval["title"] . '</a></li>';
                }
                echo "</ul>";
                  }
                  echo '</ul></li>';
                }
              }
            ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to display 3 levels hierarchical menu

Add this code in the function.php file.

```
function create_bootstrap_menu( $theme_location ) {
if ( ($theme_location) && ($locations = get_nav_menu_locations()) && isset($locations[$theme_location]) ) {
     

    $menu = get_term( $locations[$theme_location], 'nav_menu' );
    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($menu_items); die;
    $menu_list = '<ul>';
    $menucount = 1;
    $bool = true;
    foreach( $menu_items as $menu_item ) {
        if( $menu_item->menu_item_parent == 0 ) {
             
            $parent = $menu_item->ID;
             
            $menu_array = array();
            foreach( $menu_items as $submenu ) {
                if( $submenu->menu_item_parent == $parent ) {
                    $bool = true;
                    $menu_array[] = '<li class="dropdown"><a href="' . $submenu->url . '" >' . $submenu->title . '</a><ul>';
                    $parents = $submenu->ID;
                    foreach($menu_items as $submenus){
                        if( $submenus->menu_item_parent == $parents ) {
                            $menu_array[] .= '<li><a href="' . $submenus->url . '" >' . $submenus->title . '</a></li>';
                        }
                    }
                    $menu_array[] .= '</ul></li>';
                }
            }
            if( $bool == true && count( $menu_array ) > 0 ) {
                 
                $menu_list .= '<li class="dropdown">';
                $menu_list .= '<a href="'.$menu_item->url.'"><span>'.$menu_item->title.'</span> <i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i></a>';
                 
                $menu_list .= '<ul>' ."\n";
                $menu_list .= implode( $menu_array );
                $menu_list .= '</ul>';
                 
            } else {
                // echo "<pre>"; print_r($menu_item); 
                $menu_list .= '<li>';
                $menu_list .= '<a class="nav-link scrollto active" href="'.$menu_item->url.'">' . $menu_item->title . '</a>';
            }
             
        }
         
        // end <li>
        $menu_list .= '</li>';
        
        $menucount++;
    }

} else {
    $menu_list = '<!-- no menu defined in location "'.$theme_location.'" -->';
}
 
return $menu_list;
 }
```

Add this code to your menu page(header.php)

```
<?php echo create_bootstrap_menu('primary'); ?>
```